# Recreate Order - Product Grid

Tags: grid, dynamics-crm-2013

On the order entity there is a sub grid, where users can add existing/new products to that order

I want to recreate this sub grid but in a different method

Mine is that there is a Issue Entity, on that issue users can add existing/new Costs to business however when I add existing costs to business to the sub grid an error appears stating that the record is already associated with another record. This is not ideal as every time a user wants to add a record they'd have to create a new one

To try get it working so far I have the following

Issue Entity with Sub Grid to Cost To Business

There is a N:1 relationship with Issue to Cost To Business

Cost Type Entity - N:1 relationship with Cost Type to Cost To Business

On cost type the user will input a name and description of the cost

Then cost to business has a lookup to cost type which will let the user select the name and description and then input the actual cost

I have ran out of ideas as to how to get this working how I want it too, I hope I have given enough details for someone to give advice but if not ill happily try to explain further

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I fully grasp your problem but can’t you just create a N:N relationship between issue and cost of business. This allows existing costs to be added to any/all issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the N:1 relationship between Cost To Business and Issue. Then create a new N:N relationship between Cost to Business and Issue.